# Theta Criterion Violation

Tags: syntax, theta-role

Is the Theta Criterion violated in the following sentence:

[I saw  [the tall kid]]

provided that:

*saw* theta marks [the tall kid]--*see* is the main predicate (V).

*tall*  theta marks [kid] -- *tall* is the embedded predicate (ADJ).

is Theta Criterion (an argument is assigned one and only one theta role, and a theta role is assigned to one and only one argument), violated here? Because it seems that that the DP [the tall kid] is assigned two theta roles?

Comment: An embedded predicate in this sentence??

Comment: This sentence is taken from Naoli (1989) 'Predication Theory: a case study for indexing theory', p. 76, she assumes that there's an embedded predicate in this sentence with a lexical head ADJ. I can see that the Theta Criterion is violated, but I became confused, since ADJ can be predicates in some sentences like 'she is nice', and I thought to raise this question and see whether I'm right or no.

Comment: I think you need to give us a bit more about Naoli's theory, because it's not standard GB. We could try to come up with our own arguments for why attributive adjunction could be analyzed as really an embedded predicate headed by an AP, but unless by wild chance our theory is the same as Naoli's, it won't be at all relevant to your question.

Comment: Also, even if you can't explain Naoli's theory, you _definitely_ need to at least put that comment in the body of your question.

Comment: And of course it's Donna **Napoli**, not Naoli.

Comment: it's Napoli yes, apologies..

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with standard GB theta theory. In your sentence "I saw the tall kid", "the tall kid" is an NP,<sup>1</sup> with "kid" as the head. There *is* an AP here, as you suggest, but it consists of nothing but the head A "tall", and it's attached as an adjunct to the N. Something like this:

[image: <code>[NP [D the] [N' [AP [A' [A tall]]] [N kid]]]</code>]

Adjuncts don't assign theta roles to their heads. Theta assignment is the mapping of roles from a theta grid onto argument position in the tree, and adjuncts don't have arguments.<sup>2</sup>

Put another way, from closer to the semantic side of things, the way "tall" functions here is attributively, not predicatively. Attributive modifiers don't assign theta roles. So, even if "tall" does have a theta grid, there's no theta assignment by "tall" here.<sup>3</sup> Therefore, no double assignment to "kid", and therefore no violation of the theta criterion.

---

Now, from your comment:

> This sentence is taken from Naoli (1989) 'Predication Theory: a case study for indexing theory', p. 76, she assumes that there's an embedded predicate in this sentence with a lexical head ADJ.

So apparently, Napoli is arguing for some theory where attributive modification is actually predication in disguise—not just at the semantic level (as many have argued), but syntactically. We really have a syntactic clause, built out of an AP instead of a VP. I don't know if that CP is instead of the NP, or inside the NP, or inside the N', or what, but however you work it out, presumably "tall" ends up in a position to assign a theta role to "kid".<sup>4</sup>

But if there's really an A-headed clause with "tall" as the head, then "kid" is no longer the head of an NP in VP-complement position in the outer sentence. So "see" can't assign a theta role to "kid", so there is no double assignment.

But then where *does* the theta role assigned by "see" go? An unassigned theta-role would be a *different* theta criterion violation, but it's just as bad.

That's hard to answer without some picture of how Naoli analyzes "the tall kid" here. I could invent my own structure and come up with an argument for it, but the chances that it will be the same as Napoli's are pretty slim, and therefore it isn't likely to help you at all.

But in general terms, just compare it with "I saw that the kid was tall": see has [<sub>CP</sub> that the kid was tall] as an argument, "kid" doesn't get theta-marked by "see", and there's no theta criterion violation. So, if "I saw the tall kid" has a covert CP either as or inside the argument for "see", it's essentially the same, even if the details are different.

---

Or, if you look at things from a phrase-marking rather than head-marking perspective: "see" can assign a theta role to the CP or NP-with-a-CP-in or whatever [the tall kid]. But that isn't a problem, because "tall" isn't assigning a theta role to [the tall kid], it's assigning a theta role to [kid], an NP deep inside that CP.

Again, it's hard to get into details without knowing Napoli's theory, but again, compare any other case with an embedded clause: [I saw [<sub>NP</sub> the boy [<sub>CP</sub> that ate the chips]]. The fact that "see" marks [the boy that ate the chips] while "eat" also marks [the chips] isn't a theta criterion violation just because [the chips] happens to be inside [the boy that ate the chips].

---

<sub>1. Or it's a DP, with "the" as the head, and various things get more complicated, but the end result is the same, so let's ignore that here.</sub>

<sub>2. Well, they *can* have arguments *internally*, as in "the taller-than-average kid". But let's not get into that. They don't have *external* arguments: "kid" is not an argument of "tall"; "tall" is an adjunct of "kid".</sub>

<sub>3. In the original version of theta theory, only verbs had theta grids; "tall" has no theta roles to assign, so there's no issue at all. That causes problems with, e.g., Japanese "Jon wa segatakai" ("John topic-particle tall-adjective-as-predicate": "John is tall"), where "segatakai" is an adjective, which moves to I position to head the sentence, so presumably it has to be the thing assigning a theta role to the subject (well, topic, but forget that). So then maybe even in English "John is tall", the adjective "tall" is assigning the theta role through the copula in some way possibly involving lots of complicated movement. Under such theories, theta grids are only *expressed* by predicates in a "relational head position", like head of VP or IP, rather than being expressed by anything that has them. So "tall" *does* have a theta grid, but it's ignored when "tall" is the head of an AP that adjoins to an N', because it's never in a relational head position.</sub>

<sub>4. For example, maybe it's essentially the same way "segatakai" theta-assigns in the previous footnote.</sub>

Comment: This is what I normally take as the standard analysis of GB, adunjtcs don't assign theta roles (Chomsky, 1981), Williams (1980)), but in her book (by the way, it's Napoli not Naoli, I apologise), she's building something different. Anyway, I come closer to the theta theory and I discover that there are many different views by linguists, but the standard belief in GB is that adjuncts don't assign theta roles.

Comment: @TsutsuT. Unless you're committed to rejecting the Minimalist Program and being a GB diehard, I'm not sure it's worth learning the various GB alternative argument structure theories, and especially not the ones from before UTAH and Larson shells became widely adopted. None of those old solutions work under MP, and meanwhile, there's an even wider variety of MP approaches to the problem to learn. And most of the papers expect you to know standard GB, but not any of the alternatives. (That's even mostly true for non-Chomskyan theories, especially the ones that are still called "generative".)

Comment: @TsutsuT. If you search for "theta grid in minimalist program", most of the first page of results are PDFs of what look like survey papers covering the alternatives to standard-GB theta theory that have turned out to be the most important in the long run. So maybe that's a good place to start (and you can follow their references to any specific theories you find interesting).

Comment: @TsutsuT. All that being said: Given the well-known semantic equivalence (or at least parallels) between predication and attribution, a Chomskyan really _should_ be looking for a way to reduce them to the same syntax at a deeper level, as Napoli apparently did. Otherwise they're leaving a major phenomenon unexplained—in fact, one that people like Sag and Culicover later picked up as one of their arguments for abandoning MP for a CxG-flavored generative approach like HPSG or Simpler Syntax. So, maybe this book is worth studying, even if it does turn out to be obsolete.

Comment: That's what GS did. But it wasn't railroad time yet. Maybe [Schmerling's](https://brill.com/view/title/38785) got a system that would work. Looks machine-washable, anyway.

Comment: @jlawler Well, the hard part isn't just coming up with a derivation, it's finding a way to motivate the movements under accepted principles of GB, or coming up with a new principle to motivate the movements and arguing that it must be part of UG. Presumably that's what took Napoli a whole book (and maybe it's also why her derivation wasn't more widely accepted, but that also might just be a matter of bad timing).

Comment: Well, if one wants to accept and guard the sacred principles of GB, that's a matter between one and one's confessor. Me, I never converted.

Comment: @jlawler To be fair, it's not really a matter of religious orthodoxy; the principles are the only way to justify any explanation of anything, so you _have_ to use them. Of course accepting GB in the first place, yeah, that's a matter of pure faith. But if you abandon that, you have to do things like building a working parser to demonstrate that something is plausibly parseable under their account, or predicting psycholinguistic test results. What kind of science is that? Real science is saying "these principles make language perfect, therefore they must be true". :)

Comment: @jlawler (Except, of course, that everyone knows GB is heresy, because it conflicts with MP, and MP makes language really _really_ perfect instead of just perfect.)

Comment: Yeah, like I said, I never got into the angels and pinheads controversies. Like McCawley (whose syntactic theory, btw, I tend to follow), I'm a data fetishist.

Comment: Comparison with "I saw that the kid was tall" is misleading.  A better comparison is with "I saw the kid that was tall."

Comment: @amI Why is it misleading? They're both relative clauses with "tall" as a predicate inside, and that's the part that's relevant here. The only difference is external (what's extracted from the CP). Using [that was tall] adds an extra complication that's not relevant to that part of the answer—different theories differ on how "kid" gets modified, and case marked, and so on—that I didn't want to get into. (Notice that in the last section, I _do_ compare the adjective to a relative clause—once we're talking about the roles of phrases, it's a different story.)

Comment: @amI In particular, how do you explain why "[the kid [that e was tall]]" doesn't end up marking both "kid" and "e", or why that isn't a problem, without getting into specific details that differ between different versions of GB?